# variable type inside .then() chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a function `test` that takes one argument, and it can be either `string | string[]`

if it is `string[]` we just call `test` for each of its elements.

if not, we just do our stuff. and we confirm that `value` here in `string` only.

in this line `getPromise(value).then(()=>getPromise(value))`
the first `value` type is `string` which is correct,
but the other `value` inside `.then()` chain is `string | string[]`
why it's type is changed here?
and how to force using it as a string only

I don't want to use `getPromise(value as string)` because it is repeated too many times in my real code.

```
function getPromise(value: string):Promise<void>{
  return new Promise(r=>r())
}

function test(value: string | string[]): Promise<void>{
 if(value instanceof Array){
   return getPromise('')
 }
 
  // commenting out this line resolve the issue, but I don't know why?
   value = 'string'

  // the first value is a string
  // but the second one is string | string[] .... why?
  // I don't want to use `value as string`
  return getPromise(value).then(()=>getPromise(value))

}
```

for some reason, when I comment out this line `value = getValue(value)` it works. but I don't know why.

[typescript play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 2):

Since the argument is typed as `string | string[]`, it's technically possible to assign a value of a different type to it, possibly asynchronously, such as with

```
function test(value: string | string[]): Promise<void> {
  if (value instanceof Array) {
    return Promise.all(value.map(el => test(el))).then(() => {/* void */ })
  }
  value = getValue(value)
  setTimeout(() => {
    value = ['foo', 'bar']
  })
  return getPromise(value).then(() => getPromise(value))
}
```

Because the variable gets reassigned *at least once*, TypeScript will consider the variable to be of its initial type (`string | string[]`) at the top of each function inside. While inside the main function, you can check the type and thereby narrow it *for the rest of the duration of that function*, but you'll need to do the same sort of thing for every callback. TypeScript doesn't do any more in-depth analysis - it's not so smart to understand that the narrowing done in the main function should carry over to the child callback.

The best solution to this sort of situation is to never reassign variables when you don't need to - and 95% of the time, you don't need to. Instead, create *new* variables. If TypeScript doesn't see any assignments to an identifier, and the identifier's type has been narrowed already, it will not get re-widened later. Try something like

```
function test(value: string | string[]): Promise<void> {
  if (value instanceof Array) {
    return Promise.all(value.map(el => test(el))).then(() => {/* void */ })
  }
  const backupValue = getValue(value)
  return getPromise(backupValue).then(() => getPromise(backupValue))
}
```

Not reassigning variables also has [maintainability benefits](https://medium.com/tanda-developers/why-do-we-prefer-const-d805b9dc03be) - it's easier to understand code when reassignment is kept to a minimum.

Comment: for some reason, when I comment out this line `value = getValue(value)` it works. but I don't know why.

Comment: I have modified the example code for simplifying and added more details, please check it out.